# Which PCL profile should I use in my Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new in Xamarin, Xamarin.Forms and C# platform.

I'm starting the development of an app that should support Android and iOS devices. I'm using a PCL project for code sharing. Currently this project is using the `profile111` because Visual Studio has selected it by default for me. But when I try to install some NuGet packages I'm getting a message saying the package is not compatible. Something like:

> Could not install package 'DocsBrStandard 2.0.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework.

I believe this message is related with the profile I'm using, right?

So which profile should I use for my app that should support only iOS and Android devices? Is `profile111` the more appropriate for this scenario?

At least, how can I identify if a package is compatible or not with my Xamarin.Forms app?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a project that targets .NETStandard version 1.6.  Maybe it time to jump on that band-wagon as well, although I don't think that Xamarin supported the v1.x versions well.  Do consider just retrieving source from the GitHub.com project and recompiling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target .NET Standard to be able to use the `DocsBrStandard` package. So you can't work with profile based PCL if you want to use that package.

Check out this article about targeting .NET Standard with Xamarin.Forms:
https://blog.xamarin.com/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you point me if has some disadvantage when using .NET Standard instead of profile based PCL?

Comment: A downside I can think of is that you may have the same problem that you already had with the `DocsBrStandard` package - just the other way around. So that you want to use a package that is not compatible with the .NET Standard. But going for the .NET Standard is right way, since it's kind of the next generation Portable Class Library.